# What are the implications of the possibility that the BICEP2 results are caused by a self ordering scalar field transition?

Tags: cosmic-microwave-background, gravitational-waves

I've found this interesting paper that mentions another possible way to interpret the recent BICEP2 results, and that hadn't been ruled out yet [1](http://arxiv.org/abs/1403.5166). As interesting as the possibility that the BICEP2 team has observed CMB polarization due to gravitational waves resulting from a self ordering scalar field transition sounds, I would like to know what its implications/significance would be!

Comment: It would mean (1) that conclusions about inflation deriving from BICEP2 (e.g. that inflation occurred at the GUT scale) were uncertain again (2) that in addition to the Higgs field, there were many other scalar fields in nature... But now see http://arxiv.org/abs/1404.3855 : they calculate the effects of SOSF and say it's different in the details from what BICEP2 saw.

Comment: @MitchellPorter Thanks a lot for the helpful reply! The paper you linked cites some other useful papers concerned with similar topics, which helped me learn much more about it :)